# Update UI from another class

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I am trying to separate my GUI and my Logic...For example, i have one class which calculates something (calc.h/calc.m). And i have my GUI (viewController.h/viewController.m)...Now i want to update one Element of the GUI from another class... I already tried it with a Singleton, like this:

```
calc.m:

viewController *con = [viewController sharedInstance];
con.download.text = @"It Works";

viewController.m:

+ (id)sharedInstance {
static id sharedInstance;
@synchronized(self) {
    if (!sharedInstance)
        sharedInstance = [[viewController alloc] init];
    return sharedInstance;
}
}
```

But it does´t work...

UPDATE:

in my ViewController:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(receiveNotification:)
                                             name:@"UpdateDownloadLabel"
                                           object:nil];

- (void) receiveNotification:(NSNotification *) notification
{

NSDictionary* userInfo = notification.userInfo;

if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"Update"])
{
    download.text = [userInfo valueForKey:@"Test"];
}
}
```

And in my other class i post the notification like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 postNotificationName:@"UpdateDownloadLabel"
 object:nil userInfo:info];
```

But it doesn't work...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not a proper use of a singleton. If you need to notify your UI from your model you have these options:
- [delegation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html)
- [Local Notification](http://nshipster.com/nsnotification-and-nsnotificationcenter/)
- [KVO](http://nshipster.com/key-value-observing/)
The general rule is to keep your logic decoupled from your presentation, therefore your `calc` class shouldn't really know that a label named `download` exists.

Comment: Can you give a little Example with notifications?!So basically my calc class fires a notification and in my viewController i have an observer?!

Comment: That's right, when you want to send a notification you do something like this: ```[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"yourName" object:nil];```. You can also pass an object that will be handed over to your observer (in this case your view controller). Anyway, if you are new to objective c, it might be a good idea to experiment with protocols and delegation first, since they are a big part of the design of cocoa, even if we are moving towards blocks.

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't work if i register my Observer in ViewDidLoad and post a notification in another view controller...it doesn't get called...

Comment: Personally I'm a huge fan of using the KVO model for things like this.  Make your calculation result a property of the calc object and then have your view controller `[_calc addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"result"...]`  In your calc object just do `self.result = ...;`

Comment: Where do you set the notification name? You check that the name is Update, but never set it. You set `UpdateDownloadLabel`

Answer (score 0):

Example: How to use notification.

- In classA.h file

extern NSString * const ClassADidViewNotification;

- In classA.m file

NSString * const ClassADidViewNotification = @"ClassADidViewNotification";

```
Register for notification in classA.m :-     
NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
  [center addObserverForName: XXFooDidBarNotification
                      object:nil
                       queue:nil
                  usingBlock:^(NSNotification *notification)
       {
          NSLog(@"notification.object: %@", notification.object);
       }
 ];
```

Post Notification:-

```
ClassB.m
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: ClassADidViewNotification object:nil];
```